# AdMob plugin for phonegap like iAd for iphone?

Tags: iphone, cordova, admob

Is there any AdMob plugin for phonegap as we have iAd for iphone...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't because it's very straightforward to add an AdMob ad to a phonegap application by just pasting the HTML you'll obtain from http://www.admob.com/my_sites/create_site (selecting Smartphone Web) into your app wherever you want the ad to appear.